# JPA, Oracle, connect by prior, level - invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have query like this one:

```
final String q =
    "SELECT level AS \"sibling_level\", tree.* FROM category_view tree " +
    "where tree.child_market = :market " +
    "connect by prior tree.cate_xre_id = tree.cate_id " +
    "start with tree.cate_id = -1 or tree.cate_id = -18";

    final Query query = cqb.createNativeQuery(q, params, 
                                         NSISegmentationTreeViewImpl.class);

    List<NSISegmentationTreeViewImpl> segList = query.getResultList();
```

category_view is an database view.

I got sometimes:

> SQLGrammarException: ORA-00904: "NSISEGMENT0_"."SIBLING_LEVEL": invalid identifier

its not deterministic sometimes i have good result sometimes i have error.

Database ver is 11

Any ideas?

Thanks.

View def:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE "CATEGORY_VIEW" ("PARENT_ID", "PARENT_NAME", "CHILD_ID", "CHILD_NAME", "CHILD_TYPE", "CHILD_PRIORITY", "CHILD_MARKET", "CATE_XRE_ID", "CATE_ID") AS 
  WITH sibling AS
  (SELECT
    pare.category_id parent_id,
    pare.name parent_name,
    chld.category_id child_id,
    chld.name child_name,
    csga.value child_type,
    cpra.value child_priority,
    cmra.value child_market ,
    paxr.sub_category_id cate_xre_id,
    pare.category_id cate_id,
  )
SELECT
  parent_id,
  parent_name ,
  child_id,
  child_name,
  child_type,
  child_priority,
  child_market,
  cate_xre_id,
  cate_id,
FROM sibling
ORDER BY sibling.child_name;
```

I removed unnecessary fields, structure is the same.

Comment: Shall we see the View definition `category_view` ?

Comment: By quoting the alias for sibling level ( \"sibling_level\" ), you are making the column name case-sensitive. Unless you really need this (which I doubt), I'd suggest you get rid of the double quotes.

Comment: with or without quotes don't make any diffrence.